# Generalisation of the fundamental theorem of algebra (kind of!)

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

In Rudin's book I've found this exercise:

Let $f$ be a continuous complex function defined in the complex plane. Suppose there is a positive integer $n$ and a complex number different from $0$ such that:
$$\lim_{z\to \infty} z^{-n}f(z)=c$$Prove that $f(z)=0$ for some complex number $z$.

There is a hint that suggest to use the winding number. Is there a simple proof to this problem?

Comment: I have Rudin's book, but I don't recall this problem. Not that I doubt you've stated it correctly, but it might be nice to have the problem number and section, just so I can look back at it and look it over.

Comment: Thank you for responding! It's in "Principles of mathematical analysis" page 202 3ed chapter :some special functions exercise :27